# unable to find nodejs path

Tags: node.js, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue,
> please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your
> command prompt or IDE.

[image]

I already checked similar post. They said to create a Environment variable but this doesnt work. I also download nodejs from nodejs.org but that doesnt worked

[image]

**Visual Studio External Web Tool**

[image]

**Set up Environment Variables**

[image]

**Folder**

[image]

Version

[image]

Comment: "This program is blocked by group policy" is the cause that prevents VS from launching Node.js executable. About that you will have to ask your domain administrators for more details.

Comment: @LexLi do you know which file is getting blocked? becuase inside `adminrun` folder, I have access to run any files, including .exe .dll etc...

Comment: Talk to your administrators please. “I have access” is a useless clue, because the policy only blocks certain execution patterns.

Comment: i deleted `NodeJs` folder which was created from `visual studio` and re-install node from website. this worked for me